# Option -nl de ignored in my Eclipse RCP Application

Tags: localization, eclipse-rcp

I have created an eclipse RCP application with .nl1 fragments for some of the plugins. When I run the application from inside eclipse with the option:

-nl de

the application is started with german texts as expected.

But when I export the application and add the above option to the myapplication.ini file nothing happens - it use the default language english.

I have verified that all the lang fragments/.properties file are included in the build. Here is the log content:

```
!SESSION 2011-09-20 12:05:09.462 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_25
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=da_DK
Framework arguments:  -nl de
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -consolelog -nl de
```

Specifying eg. -consolelog in the myapplication.ini file works fine - I get the expected logwindow when starting myapplication.exe.

EDIT:

If I create a shortcut to my application and add  -nl de at the end of the target path:

"C:\application\myapplication.exe" -nl de

The German fragments are loaded. Why is it not possible to specify this option in the myapplication.ini file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options and values should be on separate lines, eg.

```
-nl
de
```

Answer (score 0):

Just some quick ideas:

- Have you tried to delete the workspace directory of your exported product?
- Try setting osgi.nl=de in your .ini
- Are your translations being included in the build?
- Is it really "de" or "de_DE"?

Comment: None of the above suggestions solves the problem. And yes all fragments are included and I have also tried to open some of them an verify that they contain the: messages_de.properties, messages_en.properties files.

Comment: osgi.nl = language should work and it must be added into config.ini file present in the configuration folder which is obtained after exporting the code into product.